# Uncaught ReferenceError: showCategory is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-mobile

I've defined a function named showCategory. However, for some reason my debugger is telling me that show Category is not defined. And won't load/generate the JSON pages. Also it says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined"

```
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: 'http://jsonstub.com/bike/1',
contentType: 'application/json',
beforeSend: function (request) {
    request.setRequestHeader('JsonStub-User-Key', '50caee73-c7ed-43b7-912a-7fd6fcdbfd91');
    request.setRequestHeader('JsonStub-Project-Key', '54fb5790-b2cc-432f-88ee-7d3596b700bd');
}
}).done(function showCategory( urlObj, options )
{
    var categoryName = urlObj.hash.replace( /.*category=/, "" ),
    category = categoryData[ categoryName ],    
    pageSelector = urlObj.hash.replace( /\?.*$/, "" );

if ( category ) {
    var $page = $( pageSelector ),
        $header = $page.children( ":jqmData(role=header)" ),
        $content = $page.children( ":jqmData(role=content)" ),
        markup = "<p>" + category.description + "</p><ol>",     
        content = "<p>" + category.content + "</p>",
        image = "<div class='image'><img src='"  + category.picUrl + "'></img></div>" ,
        cItems = category.items,
        numItems = cItems.length;



    for ( var i = 0; i < numItems; i++ ) {
        markup += "<li>" + cItems[i].name + "</li>";
    }
    markup += "</ol>";


    $header.find( "h3" ).html( category.name );
    $content.html( markup + content + image );
    $page.page();
    $content.find( ":jqmData(role=listview)" ).listview();
    options.dataUrl = urlObj.href;
    $.mobile.changePage( $page, options );



}
})


$(document).bind( "pagebeforechange", function( e, data ) {
if ( typeof data.toPage === "string" ) {
    var u = $.mobile.path.parseUrl( data.toPage ),
        re = /^#category-item/;
    if ( u.hash.search(re) !== -1 ) {           
        showCategory( u, data.options );
        e.preventDefault();

    }
}
});
```

I tried somethings but it won't work. Any ideas whats wrong?

[DEMO JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mariellel/h6yrdnfo/)

Comment: You do not define `showCategory` but instead you pass a named anonymous function. So move `showCategory` above the ajax (if possible) and pass the function reference in the done promise.

Answer (score 0):

Define your `showCategory`function outside of `done` method of AJAX request and then call it.

```
 function showCategory(args){
  //stuff
 }
 $.ajax({
  //ajax stuff
 }).done(function(data){showCategory(argsTakenFromData)})

 $(document).bind( "pagebeforechange", function( e, data ) {
     if ( typeof data.toPage === "string" ) {
        var u = $.mobile.path.parseUrl( data.toPage ),
        re = /^#category-item/;
        if ( u.hash.search(re) !== -1 ) {           
        showCategory( u, data.options );
           e.preventDefault();
        }
      }
  });
```

Should help.

**UPD** Changed my answer a little bit in `done` function call. But still you will get an errors, cause you forgot to define the `categoryData` array, or I don't see it's declaration, so please tell this in comments, so, try this out along with declaring the arr and tell me the result.

Comment: Okay, I did it as you said. Now it opens the third page, but still won't load the JSON.
[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mariellel/h6yrdnfo/4/)

And the error console says: Uncaught ReferenceError: urlObj is not defined

Comment: @iamalama Got busy at work, so read the upd and tell me the results.